# Trim or remove leading/trialing spaces inside the element

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I converting the html to xml. I am struggle in removing the spaces. As I used normalize() function, the spaces are removed, but the single space between text and element e.g. **`of<strong>Agricultural</strong>studies`**, `limited<i>according standard commercial</i>practices` also removed. Below i defined my input

```
 <html>
<div class="Sec">
<p class="stitle">The need of <strong>              Agricultural             </strong> studies </p>
<div class="subs1">               (a) term for leases               </div>
<div class="subs1">               (b) be limited <i>                 according standard commercial               </i> practices with maximum              </div>
<table class="table"><tr><td><p class="tablepara">                  (1) General Lease                 </p></td>
<td><p class="tablepara">                  49 years                 </p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="tablepara">                  General Permit                 </p></td><td/></tr>
<tr><td><p class="tablepara">                  Forest<sup>      1      </sup> Management Agreement                 </p></td>
<td/></tr><tr><td><p class="tablepara">                  (2) Agricultural Lease                 </p></td></tr></table>
</div>
</html>
```

I tried by using this xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html"/>
       <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
     
   <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>
    
     <xsl:template match="text()">
         <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
     </xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output I got is

```
<html>
<div class="Sec">
<p class="stitle">The need of<strong>Agricultural</strong>studies</p>
<div class="subs1">(a) term for leases</div>
<div class="subs1">(b) be limited<i>according standard commercial</i>practices with maximum</div>
<table class="table"><tr><td><p class="tablepara">(1) General Lease</p></td><td><p class="tablepara">49 years</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="tablepara">General Permit</p></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><p class="tablepara">Forest<sup>1</sup>Management Agreement</p></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="tablepara">(2) Agricultural Lease</p></td></tr></table></div>
</html>
```

I found it removes the spaces near to the text also, that is around `<i>` element and `<strong>` element

```
of<strong>Agricultural</strong>studies, limited<i>according standard commercial</i>practices
```

I need to retain the space as

```
of <strong>Agricultural</strong> studies, limited <i>according standard commercial</i> practices
```

My expected output is

```
  <html>
<div class="Sec">
<p class="stitle">The need of <strong>Agricultural</strong> studies</p>
<div class="subs1">(a) term for leases</div>
<div class="subs1">(b) be limited <i>according standard commercial</i> practices with maximum</div>
<table class="table"><tr><td><p class="tablepara">(1) General Lease</p></td><td><p class="tablepara">49 years</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="tablepara">General Permit</p></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><p class="tablepara">Forest<sup>1</sup> Management Agreement</p></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="tablepara">(2) Agricultural Lease</p></td></tr></table></div>
</html>
```

Please someone help for removing the space generically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work reasonably well:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html"/>
    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::* and following-sibling::*]">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::*]">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::*]">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (wrapped as you did in your question, not as the XSLT processor created it):

```
<html>
<div class="Sec"><p class="stitle">The need of <strong>Agricultural</strong> studies</p>
<div class="subs1">(a) term for leases</div>
<div class="subs1">(b) be limited <i>according standard commercial</i> practices with maximum</div>
<table class="table"><tr><td><p class="tablepara">(1) General Lease</p></td><td><p class="tablepara">49 years</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="tablepara">General Permit</p></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="tablepara">Forest <sup>1</sup> Management Agreement</p></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><p class="tablepara">(2) Agricultural Lease</p></td></tr></table></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Its fine, but only few correction need is, this is providing extra space for <sup> element. i.e. Forest<sup>1</sup> Management Agreemen---------------------the ouput is Forest <sup>1</sup> Management Agreemen

Comment: @Reegan So you want `some text <sup>1</sup>` to become `some text<sup>1</sup>`? Change the `<xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::*]">` to `<xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::*[not(self::sup)]]">`

Comment: Yes it is ok for known elements. But there is a possibility for unknown elements such as <sub>, <fn>, and more. Is it possible to define generically. The text and element without space should be retained as same.

Comment: @Reegan It's all a matter of thinking which template is responsible for an effect you don't want, and changing the match expressions so it won't be used in that particular situation. If your rule is *"exclude text nodes that contain text and don't end with a space"*, make a more specific match expression, something like `text()[normalize-space() != '' and substring(., string-length(), 1) != ' ']`. Keep experimenting until you have found a solution that covers all your cases.